# Can I call a parameter of a remote batch file by just assigning value of that parameter, using PsExec tools

Tags: batch-file, psexec

my problem is little tricky. I am able to remotely run a batch file using PsExec tools. But now my task demand me to run another batch file on systems remotely and this time I have to enter parameter value as prompt.

However, this could be done if you got couple of users but I got many users running and calling that batch file simultaneously. So, I am unable to enter parameter value at user end machine each time.

What I was thinking that is that possible to set a parameter value before calling remote systems and later initially called parameter triggers .bat file parameter with same value.

Something like this:

```
set /p call=%trigger%

PsExec.exe -h \\%IPADDR% -u username -p password  xyz.bat -h (%trigger%)
```

so when that xyz.bat file will open remotely then only %trigger% section will trigger out. Remember that me working of basic batch scripting on windows means no C language neither powershell scripting.